# How can we include multiple images on a page?

Tags: image

I want to add several images to one page, but I only see the space to upload one image. Is it possible to add more?

Comment: Because EE is so customizable, this question is pretty impossible to answer without you posting more information about how things are set up currently. Please edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Think it's a perfectly clear question from a new user of ExpressionEngine - they've used the default EE file upload field which is utterly useless and can only cope with a single file. So looking to the community to suggest best practice methods, which Yuri has done. Possibly better wording for the question is: "I'd like an entry to have more than one image for a single field - how can I do this?"

Answer (score 2):

If this is regular File field, then you can only upload only file to it. If you need multiple files within one field, it is best to set up Grid field with one column being File field. This will require some changes in template code as well.